Simplifying an expression containing NonThreadable + Dot gives unexpected result?
Bug introduced in 14.1.

Consider this example
vec//Attributes={NonThreadable};

expr={a,b} . ({c,d}+vec);

expr//Simplify

expr//Distribute//Simplify


vec is not threaded over list as expected.
However,
expr={a,a} . ({c,c}+vec);

expr//Simplify

expr//Distribute//Simplify


In this case vec has been threaded when Simplify.
Is my understanding of NonThreadable correct? Or is it that Simplify has not handled NonThreadable properly?

Seems that I've made a mistake in the (now deleted) answer. I agree this seems to be a bug.

@xzczd It seems that NonThreadable is not simply an Attribute that protect the specified head from being threaded, but an Attribute that is highly coupled with symbolic tensor functionalities. vec-vec gives SymbolicZerosArray[] instead of 0.

I have reported to WRI and they agreed that "the NonThreadable attribute is not behaving properly". Hopefully this will be improved in the future.
